# Meta-Meta: Reopening discussions

Tags: discussion, meta

What is the recommended way to re-open a discussion (for example on the topic of what is considered off-topic)? Some discussions have one or two comments, but disappear from the main sites after a while before a decision is reached. Some issues might even need re-consideration because the circumstances that lead to a decision have changed. How can we re-open such discussions? Just posting a new answer or comment won't always get it the attention it deserves, but posting the same question again also seems weird... Any Ideas?

Comment: If the topic you wish to discuss is relevant right now, IMO it should be fine to bring it up again, even if it is a duplicate. Meta does not need to be as strict as main, if you want to bring something up again, after like a year or two, just do it, explain how it may be a duplicate but why you think it is worth bringing up again now.

Comment: "Reconsidering" would actually make a new question.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just post a new question and explain in the question that while there is a duplicate it is different and why you think it needs to be discussed again in a separate discussion.

We aren't *as* strict about duplicates here on Meta.  We *usually* suggest though that if you're opening a new discussion on something that you link back to the original discussion(s) for context, though.